# how to import file to main.js to use it in the Vue js project

Tags: javascript, vue.js, module, vue-component

I have created a module `sc.js` like this one:

[image]

Then I imported it into `main.js` in VUE.JS just like:

[image]

Now I would like to use it in my components:

[image]

but if I do it I got an `undefined`

How to fix it and be able to use my method? Thanks for any help!

Comment: can you try this `Vue.prototype.time = time` instead of `Vue.use`

Comment: @SumanMajhi It works, Thank you .. what if the file contains more than one function .. how can i do it?

Comment: apply this `Object.assign(Vue.prototype, allFunc)` and `import allFunc from '@/script/sc'` and do a export default from sc.js for all function. Do let me know if it worked, will add in ans section

Comment: @SumanMajhi i put export in front of each function in ```sc.js``` and in ```main.js``` i do this ```import fnc from "@/scripts/sc";``` and this ```Object.assign(Vue.prototype, fnc)``` and in ```home.vue``` i do this ```console.log(this.fnc.time());``` but i get an err: ```Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'time')```

Comment: You have to `export default { func1, func2, func3 .... }` in sc.js and in main.js `import allFunc from '@/script/sc'` and this `Object.assign(Vue.prototype, allFunc)`. In the vue file, all you have to do is `this.func1()`